# Connect on-promise database to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, active-directory, vpn, sharepoint-online

I having some difficulties connecting on-promise database to SharePoint online.

Database connection is required VPN, once the user is out of the local network.

Basically, We have some Database views that, we would like to  display them on our SharPoint online.

SharePoint 2013 Online E3

SQL Server

Active Directory

we need a guide, how to access this Database on SharePoint online without using public PI. Basically, we are trying find a way to connect this database with secure connection.

The aim is developing asp.net app, 
The list of option

WCF

Web API technology

Comment: What is wrong with question?

Comment: nothing to do with programming

Comment: It's my bad, I didn't mention ASP.NET development part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Connect SharePoint:**
[image]

> Using `Azure Hybrid Connection` ,BCS with Azure Web App hosting WCF endpoint, we can now expose on-premises `SQL data` to SharePoint `Online and Cloud` by external content types (`ECTs`) or `SharePoint Hosted Apps`.

**Below are `two` approaches by which `BCS` can connect these data sources to `SharePoint`:**

```
1. Azure Web App hosting WCF Service and External Lists
2. Azure Web App hosting WCF Data Service and Hosted Apps
```

[image]

**Pros:**

> The advantage of using this `approach is the reusability` of External
>   Content Types (`ECT`). ECTs can be used across multiple lists and sites
>   in the same site collection. ECTs can also be used for `complex`
>   associations `across multiple types of data`.

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
// TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);

config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;

config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
}
```

Comment: WCF endpoint or Web API is more secure

Comment: web Api is secure, you may have secondary selection as Wcf endpoint.. [click here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/who-is-winner-web-api-or-wcf/)